# RegionBounds wrong with small change

Tags: bugs, numerics, regions

For the following:

```
RegionBounds[ImplicitRegion[0 <= y <= Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, y}]]
```

I get the correct value of `{{-1, 1}, {0, 1}}`.

However, this:

```
RegionBounds[ImplicitRegion[$MachineEpsilon <= y <= Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, y}]]
```

produces `{{-0.681805, 0.942851}, {0.0547502, 0.570898}}`.

Any workarounds, or perhaps explanations?

Thanx.

Comment: Works with the exact value: `RegionBounds[ImplicitRegion[2^-52 <= y <= Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, y}]]`

Comment: Thanx! (I needed to wrap in `N[]`` to see that.)
Any explanations?

Comment: (Should I be reporting a bug?)

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a bug.  Oddly using `SetPrecision[$MachineEpsilon, p]` for `p = 16, 17, 18,...` gives seemingly random results.

Comment: I think the explanation is that it uses different methods on exact input `2^-52` than on floating-point input, floating-point being what the value of `$MachineEpsilon` is.  But I don't know exactly what goes on inside.

Comment: I'm putting in the [tag:bugs] tag. Could someone with e.g. version 10 check this as well, and perhaps put in the usual bug header?

Comment: Thanx, J.M., appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a workaround, use exact numbers

```
Clear["Global`*"];

RegionBounds[ImplicitRegion[0 <= y <= Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, y}]]

(* {{-1, 1}, {0, 1}} *)

RegionBounds[
  ImplicitRegion[
   SetPrecision[$MachineEpsilon, Infinity] <= y <= Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, y}]] // 
 N

(* {{-1., 1.}, {2.22045*10^-16, 1.}} *)
```

or

```
RegionBounds[
  ImplicitRegion[
   Rationalize[$MachineEpsilon, 0] <= y <= Sqrt[1 - x^2], {x, y}]] // N

(* {{-1., 1.}, {2.22045*10^-16, 1.}} *)
```